# Custom ListView with Separator gets crazy

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-view

I'm trying to implement a custom ListView which has separators in it. This is the code:

SingleTitle:

```
public class SingleTitle {
    String mTitle;
    int[] mInterval;

    public SingleTitle(String title, int[] interval) {
        mTitle = title;
        mInterval = interval;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return mTitle;
    }

    public int[] getInterval() {
        return mInterval;
    }
}
```

TitleCategory:

```
public class TitleCategory {
String mTitle;

public TitleCategory(String title) {
    mTitle = title;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return mTitle;
}
}
```

list_category_divider.xml:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<include
    android:id="@+id/list_item_section_text"
    layout="@android:layout/preference_category" />

</ LinearLayout >
```

The method which returns the list:

```
    public static List<Object> getStructuredTitles(Context context) {
    List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
    String[] mTitles = getCategoriesTitles(context);
    String[] mParts = getPartsTitles(context);

    list.add(new TitleCategory(mParts[0]));
    list.add(new SingleTitle(mTitles[0], CATEGORIES_INTERVALS[0]));
    list.add(new TitleCategory(mParts[1]));
    list.add(new SingleTitle(mTitles[1], CATEGORIES_INTERVALS[1]));
    list.add(new SingleTitle(mTitles[2], CATEGORIES_INTERVALS[2]));
    list.add(new SingleTitle(mTitles[3], CATEGORIES_INTERVALS[3]));
    list.add(new SingleTitle(mTitles[4], CATEGORIES_INTERVALS[4]));
    list.add(new TitleCategory(mParts[2]));
    list.add(new SingleTitle(mTitles[5], CATEGORIES_INTERVALS[5]));
    list.add(new SingleTitle(mTitles[6], CATEGORIES_INTERVALS[6]));
    list.add(new SingleTitle(mTitles[7], CATEGORIES_INTERVALS[7]));
    list.add(new SingleTitle(mTitles[8], CATEGORIES_INTERVALS[8]));
    list.add(new SingleTitle(mTitles[9], CATEGORIES_INTERVALS[9]));
    list.add(new SingleTitle(mTitles[10], CATEGORIES_INTERVALS[10]));
    list.add(new TitleCategory(mParts[3]));
    list.add(new SingleTitle(mTitles[11], CATEGORIES_INTERVALS[11]));

    return list;
}
```

My custom adapter:

```
  public class TitlesAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context context;
private List<Object> entries;

public TitlesAdapter(Context context, List<Object> entries) {
    this.context = context;
    this.entries = entries;
}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return entries.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return entries.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Object entry = entries.get(position);
    boolean isCategory = (entry instanceof TitleCategory);

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(isCategory ? R.layout.list_category_divider : R.layout.list_items_simple, null);
    }

    if (isCategory) {
        TitleCategory tc = (TitleCategory)entry;
        convertView.setClickable(false);

        Log.d("DBG", "Entry: " + position + " | " + tc.getTitle());
        TextView tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(android.R.id.simple_list_item_2);
        if (tv != null) tv.setText(tc.getTitle());
    } else {
        SingleTitle tc = (SingleTitle)entry;

        Log.d("DBG", "Entry: " + position + " | " + tc.getTitle());
        TextView tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        if (tv != null) 
            tv.setText(tc.getTitle());
    }
    return convertView;

}


public List<Object> getList() {
    return entries;
}

public void setList(List<Object> newentries) {
    entries = newentries;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

}
```

**My problem:**
The app initially draws the list well, but when I scroll up and down the list it messes up the entries. However the output generated in logcat is right, but Android messes up the list. Any idea?

UPDATE:
[image: Correct one]
[image: Wrong one]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to implement [`getViewTypeCount()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getViewTypeCount%28%29). In your case it should return 2.

```
@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 2;
}
```

Android probably makes some assumptions on a single view type, if that method is not implemented.

Also override `getItemViewType(int position)` to make it return either `0` or `1` based on whether the index in the list is a 'category' or 'title'.

```
@Override 
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
     ...
}
```

Comment: try to add public int getItemViewType(int position) as well.

Comment: glad it works. there is a great introduction on [ListView](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70) by [Romain Guy](http://stackoverflow.com/users/298575/romain-guy) and Adam Powell available at youtube.